# Defibrillator energy?

Tags: power-supply, medical

Just been reading [this](http://www.globalrph.com/acls_adult_cardiac_arrest.htm) where this statement is made:

> If the patient is in Ventricular tachycardia (VT) or ventricular
>   fibrillation (VF) on the monitor, immediately apply the pads and shock
>   the patient with 120-200 Joules on a biphasic defibrillator or 360
>   Joules on a monophasic defibrillator.

That seems like a huge energy to dump into someone. Do they really do this?

Comment: Yes. The heart is a bit isolated from the outside - you need to shoot through the lung.

Comment: If the patient's only option of life is a massive surge of energy then it's worth a try. Mind you, anyone who hasn't paid there electricity bill gets a "do not resuscitate" label pinned to their forehead.

Comment: Yep, and depending on the exact circumstances that means a whopping 40+ Amps for a few ms. It hurts. A lot.

Comment: What velocity will that import to a heart full of fluid? The resistance is fairly high.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane: Depends on what you mean by high, but the common ballpark is 50-150Ω with a great potential for outliers (fun fact: modern devices have different waveforms for different impedances)

Answer (score 1):

200J is not a lot of energy. For instance 200J will heat a glass of water about 0.2-0.25 kelvin. An average cellphone-battery holds about 30kJ.
When discussing electrical and electronic systems energy is commonly specified in Wh but one joule is equal to one Ws (and one Wh equals 3.6kJ since one hour is 3.6ks)

Comment: It may be not a lot of energy, but I gave myself about 1J from a HV capacitor by mistake and it hurt like hell. Not a mistake I want to make again!

Comment: I guess that explains why defibrillation is performed under general anesthesia when treating arrythmias!

Comment: @user1890202 I would also assume it rather stresses the chest muscles and you are going to be a bit sore after being zapped.

Comment: Another example: [400J (only twice the energy) within 1ms blowing up a _cheap_ multimeter](https://youtu.be/M-FZP1U2dkM?t=374) at the EEVblog.